# docker-storage-setup package is not available on my rhel 7 box? how do i get it? I need to create a thin pool with device mapper.

Tags: docker, centos, rhel, device-mapper

i am trying to create a thin pool on my rhel box to use with devicemapper as it is the recommended way to use docker storage. But unfortunately i am not able to find docker-storage-setup package on my machine which is needed to create the thin pool. How do i do this? And first of all, is it actually needed?

Answer (score 0):

`docker-storage-setup` is not required to setup the direct thin pools, but it makes it easier.

The most recent versions of Docker (17.06+) are able to [manage a single volume pool for you](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/#configure-direct-lvm-mode-for-production) via `daemon.json`

```
{
  "storage-driver": "devicemapper",
  "storage-opts": [
    "dm.directlvm_device=/dev/xdf",
    "dm.thinp_percent=95",
    "dm.thinp_metapercent=1",
    "dm.thinp_autoextend_threshold=80",
    "dm.thinp_autoextend_percent=20",
    "dm.directlvm_device_force=false"
  ]
}
```

If you have more specific requirements then follow the "Configure direct-lvm mode manually" a bit further down in the [direct lvm for production instructions on docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/#configure-direct-lvm-mode-manually)